# click event for nested table td element without first table td

Tags: jquery, html-table

If a user clicks on the `img` element the alert shows `test-image` and the `two-side-text`. However my need is to only show `test-image`. How can I do that?

```js
$("body").on('click', 'td', function(evt) {
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="Two-side-text">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="test-image">
                <img src="img-placeholder.png">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="test-paragraph">
                <p>
                  test paragraph
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the event bubbling up the DOM to the parent `td` elements. To do that you can call `stopPropagation()` on the event, like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'td', function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="Two-side-text">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="test-image">
                <img src="img-placeholder.png">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="test-paragraph">
                <p>
                  test paragraph
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't see your answer, will delete mine.